# Present continous and present simple

Tags: present-tense, progressive-aspect

Why do we say, "Who is that man? What does he want", but, "Who is that man? Why is he looking at us". If the second is okay, which I am sure it is, why can't we say, "Who is that man? What is he wanting from us?".

Thanks

Comment: Note that you *could* say "*What is he wanting?*", it's just that, well, [no one does](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what+does+he+want%2C+what+is+he+wanting).

Comment: @DanBron Take a look at Indian English. It is the sort of thing I can hear being said in an Indian accent. I think they make more use of the present continuous than we do.

Comment: @WS2 I am having a doubt...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The construction employed in the question is determined by the construction employed in the declarative sentence - the 'answer' you are looking for.

*Look* is an *activity* verb, and usually takes the progressive construction in reporting a present action; in a question, subject/auxiliary inversion operates with the existing auxiliary *BE*:

> That man **is** looking at us. → Why **is** the man looking at us?

A simple present, *That man **looks** at us*, would be unusual, an 'historical present' which ordinarily occurs only in literary or news-reporting contexts.

*Want* is a *stative* verb. Such verbs are not usually cast in the progressive<sup>†</sup>, but in the simple present; since there is no auxiliary, this requires the 'dummy' auxiliary *DO* for subject/auxiliary inversion in a question:

> That man **wants** something. → What **does** that man want?

---

<sup>†</sup>This does not mean that they may not be cast in the progressive; but when this occurs it usually signals either a different sense or an unusual context which calls for 'recategorization' of the verb.